# How do you escape * for du?

Tags: ruby, linux, unix

The ruby library I'm using, [Rye](http://delano.github.io/rye), adds quotes around the search string. So instead of `du -sh *` the query becomes `du -sh '*'`

How can I escape the asterisk? `du -sh '\\*'` does not work

Comment: What do expect escaped asterisk to do? Most shells should not expand it when it's inside quoted string.

Comment: Perhaps you want to remote execute `sh -c "du -sh *"` if you want the `*` to be expanded at the remote site.

Comment: As already correctly stated by @SergioTulentsev you need to remove the quotes. Escaping doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it should be possible by doing this

```
rbox = Rye::Box.new [...]
rbox.disable_safe_mode
rbox.execute 'du -sh *'
```